what dependencies I should update, when I have updated my npm to version 20.17.0 (LTS) ? I have got many errors in my project
Sorry, I am a newbie and am learning the course of react and redux. After updating npm to v20.17.0 (LTS), my project started to run into errors and I dont know how to solve these problems. Please help me.
enter image description here
I have tried to use this command  npm audit fix --force, delete modules and dependencies and reinstalled with npm i. Than I have created the .env file in my source-folder with the code
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
